# file access in debian python with h5py

Tags: python, linux

We have an problem with python h5py in debian. The data file is in the same directory as the script file. And i'v tried to give the file test.h5 right with chmod -r and chmod 777.
Error is show up in normal user as in root access.

When we run this script:

```
## Libarys importeren
import wradlib

#inlezen hdf5 file en config
raw = wradlib.io.read_OPERA_hdf5("test.h5")
```

We get this error:

```
root@wxserv:/home/kbroeren# python light.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "light.py", line 5, in <module>
raw = wradlib.io.read_OPERA_hdf5("test.h5")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wradlib-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/wradlib/io.py",     line 652, in read_OPERA_hdf5
f = h5py.File(fname, "r")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 150, in __init__
fid = make_fid(name, mode, fapl)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 45, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDONLY, fapl=plist)
File "h5f.pyx", line 70, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1618)
IOError: unable to open file (File accessability: Unable to open file)
root@wxserv:/home/kbroeren#
```

Can someone help us out with this issue ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be that you either do not have a file called `test.h5` in the local directory, or you don't actually have permissions to open it.  If the former, create a file called `test.h5` for you to work with.  But based on the error, it sounds like it may exist, but have permissions like `---------`.  If so, you might try running `chmod u+r test.h5` and rerunning your program.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Too bad it doesnt work. I download the files automatically from an FTP server with crontab. This is the permission of the file: -rwx-wx-wx 1 kbroeren kbroeren   994088 Apr  1 20:14 test.h5

Comment: If you've downloaded the file locally, which you appear to have done, then you should be able to get the permissions with `ls -l`.  Are you trying to run the script locally when the file is remote?

Comment: -rwx-wx-wx 1 kbroeren kbroeren   994088 Apr  1 20:14 test.h5